# Get header lines from FASTA file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fasta

I have a multi-line input file which looks like this

```
>WP_046827164.1 cation transporter [Afipia massiliensis]
MRTEQGVLRLSIAVTLALAGLGILFGLLSGSFAIVFDGVYALIDAVMTILALLVANLIAASTREGGSKSR
LIAQFTMGFWHLEPMVLGLNGILLMGAAIYALITAIGSLLTGGRELAFDQAIIYAVVTMLAAIGMAIFDI
KANLTIRSNFIALDAKAWMMSAALTAALLVAFIFGYMIQGTHLKWMSPYIDPAALAIVCLIVIPIPIGTV
RQALADALLVTPPDLMRQVEAIAAQVVLRYQFLSYRAYVARVGRGRQIELYFIVPPGLPPRRLEEWDKIR
DEIGDAIGNDTPDRWLSIVFTTDQEWAE

>WP_014775528.1 cation transporter [Alistipes finegoldii]
MSGEAEIRKKKIYRVTFIGFAVNLLLAGIKLAAGILGRSGAMVADAVHSFSDMATDVVVIAFAKISAKPK
DEGHDYGHGKYETLATIIISLALAAVGTGILVNSIGAIRVVVDGGLLPRPGTVALLAAAVSIVVKEILYR
YTVREGRRVSSPSMIANAWHHRSDALSSLGTLAGIGCAYFLGDKWRIADPIAALVVAVFIFKIAFDLIRT
GLDELLERSLPEDVEEEILRVVAANPEVREPHNLRTRRIGASIAVEVHVRVDGAMSVCRSHELTEDIERR
LRARFGEGTMIAIHVEPLKAACRAE
```

... so on

We need to get all the header line starting with ">" sign and put them in array so that further operations can be done. We are able to catch the file content, but not able to extract the headers.

```
import sys
import re


def interact():
    # type: () -> stringfile
    filename = raw_input ( 'Please Give the file name:  ' )
    return filename


def load_file(filename):
    # type: (object) -> eachlines
    file_content = open ( filename )
    all_content = file_content.read ()  # type: str
    file_content.close ()
    #return all_content
    for _ in all_content:  # type: str
        if re.match(r">", _):
            return "_"


# all_lines = load_file(interact())
print load_file(interact())
```

How can this code be fixed to extract the headers as well?

Comment: Sounds like this can be done rather easily by RE? Otherwise you could also have a look at the split functiin

Comment: This is a FASTA file, I'd recommend looking at [`biopython`](https://biopython.org/), specifically [`SeqIO`](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO). If you have other questions, come over to the [tag:bioinformatics] tag

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The first thing I noticed is that you've tagged the question [tag:python-3.x] but you're using Python 2 syntax and builtins.  Is that the problem? Please make a [mre]. Just saying that something's wrong isn't helpful - you need to say what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`biopython`](http://biopython.org/):

```py
from Bio import SeqIO

headers = []
with open("in.fa", "r") as f:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(f, "fasta"):
        headers.append(record.description)

print(headers)
# ['WP_046827164.1 cation transporter [Afipia massiliensis]',
#  'WP_014775528.1 cation transporter [Alistipes finegoldii]']
```